# How to get Paragraph or any drawn text bounding box in reportlab

Tags: python, reportlab

I'm using reportlab to generate documents with their layout labels.

For example:
Document 1:

(x1,y1,x2,y2) Title

(x1,y1,x2,y2) Figure

(x1,y1,x2,y2) Text

(x1,y1,x2,y2) Table

...
and so on

To be able to do that I want to be able to know the bounding box of the drawn text on the screen.

I've hit a wall trying to do this, all elements require only the starting position of the content.

Example Code:

```
styleSheet = getSampleStyleSheet()    
style = styleSheet['BodyText']
text = 'text example'
P=Paragraph(text, style)
P.drawOn(canv,0,aH) 
w, h = #the width and height of the whole paragraph (0, aH, 0+w, aH-h)
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I added an example